# Input radio ng-model not updated after all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I try to solve a puzzle why an ng-model of input[radio] controls is not set as I expect.
When a page is loaded all radios are initiated correctly. Clicking on different controls changes the radioVal variable - its value is rendered in the page.

The problem is that it looks like it takes place only in a DOM. When I debug the code the `$scope.radioVal` is always the same ... 
The isolated scope of `modalDialog` does not contain the `radioVal` property.

In which scope the radio `ng-model` is created ? Is it a different instance of it?

---

The working code can be found [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvlax/WqGs6/).

---

My html code is:

```
<div ng-app = "app"> 
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">         
   <a ng-click="showModalDlg()">Click me</a>
   <br/><br/>
   <modal-dialog show="showModal" action="actionFun">                        
    <form>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="radioVal" value="1">One<br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="radioVal" value="nothing changes me">Two<br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="radioVal" value="3">Three<br/>
          <br/><br/>
          The model changes in the DOM as expected: <b>radioVal = {{radioVal | json}}</b>
          <br/>
          but by pressing the Action button you can see that the model has not been modified. 
    </form>                        
    <a class="button" action>Action</a>                     
    </modal-dialog>
   </div>
</div>
```

My angular code:

```
angular.module('common', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.showModal = false;
        $scope.radioVal = "nothing changes me";

        $scope.showModalDlg = function() {
           $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        };

        $scope.actionFun = function() {
           console.log('actionFun ...' + $scope.radioVal);
        };        

    }]).directive('modalDialog',
        function () {
            return {
               restrict: 'E',
               scope: {
                  show: '=',
                  action: '&',
               },
               replace: true,
               transclude: true,
               link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                        scope.hideModal = function () {
                           scope.show = false;
                           scope.$apply();
                        };

                        $('a[hide]', element).on('click', function(){
                           scope.hideModal();
                        });

                        $('a[action]', element).on('click', function(){
                           console.log('There is no radioVal in isolated scope either ... ' + scope.radioVal);
                           scope.action()();
                           scope.hideModal();
                        });
                  },
            template: '<div class=\'ng-modal\' ng-show=\'show\'><div class=\'ng-modal-overlay\'></div><div class=\'ng-modal-dialog\' ng-style=\'dialogStyle\'><div class=\'ng-modal-dialog-content\' ng-transclude></div></div></div>'
        }
    });

  angular.module('app', ['common'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ALWAYS put a **dot** in **`ng-model`**

You are currently trying to pass a primitive to a nested scope which will break 2 way binding. If you pass an object however it will maintain reference to the original object

Simply changing :

```
$scope.radioVal = "nothing changes me";
```

To:

```
 $scope.myModel={radioVal : "nothing changes me"};
```

And using the dot in `ng-model`

```
<input  ng-model="myModel.radioVal">
```

changes the inheritance and therefore the binding.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FAmad/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, your reasoning makes sens and works.
But $scope.showModal from the outer controller mainCtrl is also a primitive and a two way binding still works here (see: scope.hideModal = function () { scope.show = false; ...  in the directive. I am afraid I still do not understand something ..

Comment: right but that is being passed to the modal directive that is declaring a 2 way binding with your isolated scope. Internally angular is watching it for you. Cases are different.. ng-model is also a directive. Will see the `use dot` all over posts here.

Comment: Yes. I think "ng-model is also a directive" is what I missed trying to understand my problem. I would not be surprised if the right radioVal that I could not found (that one displayed in a page with its changing value) was managed by its [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) not by my controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a `scope` object in your directive, it means that you create an isolated scope for each instance of that directive. You need to pass the `radioVal` to the isolated (child) scope you create with the directive.
HTML:

```
<modal-dialog show="showModal" action="actionFun" value="radioVal">
```

JS:

```
scope: {
            show: '=',
            action: '&',
            radioVal: '='
       },
```

Comment: yarons, thank you for the hint, but I would prefer to keep my 'generic' modal dialog decoupled from any model used by controls embedded in the modal dialog content (see charlietfl response).